# stop css animated blinking image on click

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have an image that I have made blink by using css. The image looks like a cursor (of sorts).  It is positioned over a textarea. When the user clicks the image or the textarea, I want the blinking image to disappear. So far, the thing just keeps blinking. How can I make it stop for good?

HTML:

```
<form id="commentsForm">
<div id="textareaWrap">
<img src="img/caret.png" id="blinking_caret" title="blinking caret" />
<textarea id="formStory" placeholder=""></textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
    @keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    49% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes blink
{
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    49% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
    #textareaWrap {
        position: relative;
    }
        #blinking_caret {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0; left: 0;
            animation: blink 1s;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            -webkit-animation: blink 1s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            z-index: 2;
        }
    #formStory {
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        background-color: #f1f0f0;
        height: 400px;
        cursor: text;
        outline: none;
    }
```

jquery:

```
$('#formStory').click(function(){
    $('#blinking_cursor').stop( true, true ).fadeOut();
    $("#formStory").attr("placeholder","Start here ...");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `$('#blinking_cursor')` in your jQuery. Your image has ID of `#blinking_caret` - update your jQuery to select correct ID.

And if you simple want image to disappear, just do `$('#blinking_caret').hide();`

Comment: Embarrassing, but true.

Answer (score 1):

Why even use JavaScript? This can be accomplished using only CSS. The code (and fiddle) will hide the caret whenever the textarea has focus or has text (using HTML5 required attribute).

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/7ePSU/

HTML:

```
<form id="commentsForm">
    <div id="textareaWrap">
        <textarea id="formStory" required placeholder=""></textarea>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#textareaWrap {
    position:relative; width:200px;
}
#textareaWrap textarea {
    position:relative; width:100%; height:100px; z-index:1; font-size:12px;
}
#textareaWrap .caret {
    -webkit-animation: blink 1s steps(1) infinite;
    position:absolute; left:3px; top:2px; z-index:2;
    width:1px; height:1em; background:#000;
}
#textareaWrap textarea:focus + .caret,
#textareaWrap textarea:valid + .caret {display:none;}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0% {opacity: 1;}
    50% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

*Note: You would still need JavaScript to do the placeholder. (You could model it similarly as the `.caret`, but that's not necessary). Your question wasn't about the placeholder, though, so I was just showing you how you could accomplish the cursor.*

Answer (score 0):

Keep the ID of the element, but apply the CSS via a class. You still get fast/absolute selection, but can do this in your click function:

```
$('#blinking_cursor').removeClass('whateverClassName');
```

+1 to Yuriy. Totally missed that!